# How to understand "torch.randn()" size* parameter arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch

From what I understand, `torch.randn(layers/depth, rows, columns)`, which can be seen when executing: `torch.randn(2, 3, 3)` ==> 2 layers (3x3) matrix:

```
tensor([[[ 1.4838,  1.2926,  1.6147],
     [ 0.7923,  0.6414, -0.2676],
     [-0.1949,  0.3859, -0.6940]],

    [[ 0.2454, -1.9215, -0.3078],
     [ 0.8544,  0.9726,  0.0330],
     [ 0.3579,  0.8247,  2.1288]]])
```

But what does adding an extra term in the size* parameter imply? As in: `torch.randn(2, 1, 3, 3)`

```
tensor([[[[ 0.6206, -1.3697, -0.2267],
      [ 1.0511,  2.3375, -0.9598],
      [-0.8148, -0.0911, -2.1211]]],


    [[[ 0.0659,  1.0764,  0.6150],
      [-1.7226,  0.5038, -0.9544],
      [-0.6447, -0.3325,  0.2048]]]])
```

What did the "1" add into the Tensor created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each number you are introducing refers to a dimension of the matrix. It is hard for humans to visualize more than 3 dimensions, but computers are fine with it.

In this particular case, you can think about the extra dimension as something like a batch size.

Comment: It seems like the first element represents the number of "batches" (roughly), while the second represents the number of "layers/dimensions", and the last two represent height and width. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you could think about it as torch.randn(n_batches, n_channels, height, width). At the end, what you are doing is just defining all different dimensions of your tensor.

Answer (score 0):

In short you just added a dimension with a single element. Note the additional brace.

Perhaps rewriting the output will help you to understand what happened:

```
torch.randn(2, 3, 3)
> tensor(
tensor(
[    # 1st dim - 1st element
  [  # 2nd dim - 1st element
    [ 1.4838,     # 3rd dim - 1st element
      1.2926,     # 3rd dim - 2nd element
      1.6147],    # 3rd dim - 3rd element
    [ 0.7923,  0.6414, -0.2676], # 2nd dim - 2nd element ( 3rd dim ... )
    [-0.1949,  0.3859, -0.6940]  # 2nd dim - 3rd element ( 3rd dim ... )
  ], #1st dim - 2nd element
  [  ## .. same as above
    [ 0.2454, -1.9215, -0.3078],
    [ 0.8544,  0.9726,  0.0330],
    [ 0.3579,  0.8247,  2.1288]
  ]
])
```

```
torch.randn(2, 1, 3, 3)
> 
tensor(
[     # 1st dim - 1st element
  [   # 2nd dim - 1st element
    [ # 3rd dim - 1st element
      [ 0.6206,  # 4th dim - 1st element
        -1.3697, # 4th dim - 2nd element
        -0.2267],# 4th dim - 3rd element
      [ 1.0511,  2.3375, -0.9598], # 3rd dim - 2nd element
      [-0.8148, -0.0911, -2.1211]  # 3rd dim - 3rd element
    ]
     # 2nd dim - nothing more ...
  ], # 1st dim - 2nd element
  [  # .. same as above
    [  
      [ 0.0659,  1.0764,  0.6150],
      [-1.7226,  0.5038, -0.9544],
      [-0.6447, -0.3325,  0.2048]
    ]
  ]
])
```